# JavaScript: Convert URL string to a Unique identifier

Tags: javascript, guid

I would like to convert a URL string into a shorter unique identifier. I would like to use this GUID as a CSS class. It is also important that if I pass the same URL/string to the GUID generator function, the function should return the exactly same unique identifier.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This sounds very much like an "X/Y problem". For instance, maybe you want lots of clickable elements to take you to webpages as well as execute some JavaScript - you don't have to use CSS classes for that. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: Can you show an example of the GUID syntax?  Is it all numbers, alpha, alphanumeric, special characters, etc..

Comment: What you want ist a hash function.

Comment: _"if I pass the same URL/string to the GUID generator function, the function should return the exactly same unique identifier."_ That's not how GUIDs are supposed to work. Sounds like you want a hash, such as MD5 or SHA1. @Drew The written representation of GUIDs generally consists of hex digits 1 - F.

Answer (score 0):

As I right understand, you need uniq string as identifier. Why don't you use REST representation? One URL represent only one uniq state.